# java simple output of name and age

Tags: java, output

Im kind of new to java and im struggling very hard at this one. I just want to make a syso with the age and name of Stefan

```
    public class Person {

    public int alter;
    public String placeofbirth;

    public Person(int alter, String placeofbirth) {
    this.alter = alter;
    this.placeofbirth = placeofbirth;
    }

    Person stefan = new Person(19, "Berlin");

    public String toString() {
    return "test" + stefan;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(stefan);
    }

    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Would be very grateful to get help

Comment: You have to add the @override annotation to toString method to overwrite it. System.out.println will call automatically the toString method.

Comment: @ChW The `@Override` tag only produces an error when the method doesn't actually overrides a method, it's not necessary but very useful.

Comment: Move the instantiation of `Person` into the `main` method.

Comment: The `toString()` of `Person` would create an awful `StackOverflowError` because it's a recursive method. Change it to `public String toString(){ return "test "+alter+" "+placeofbirth;}`. Also the Person `stefan` isn't in the scope of the main method.

Answer (score -4):

just you need write `return "test" + placeofbirth ;` insdead of : return "test" + stefan;`

Comment: Nope, `println(Object)` automatically calls `toString()`

Comment: Yes sorry my bad i dont see he call recursively the function toString

Comment: Well your answer moves into the right direction.